# What way to choose in case of merging in my case?

Tags: git, merge, repository, git-merge, rebase

I have a `develop` branch and `fix` branch. `Fix` branch is behind top of `develop` - 5 commits.

What is the best and *easiest* way to merge it to `develop` ?
Firstly rebase ?
Can you show me exact commands ?

Answer (score 1):

First ensure both of your branches are latest:

```
git pull origin develop
```

Switch back to `fix` branch

```
git checkout fix
git pull origin fix
```

Rebase `fix` branch on `develop`

```
git rebase develop
git push
```

Go back to `develop` branch and merge `fix` into it

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff  fix

git push
```

Answer (score 0):

The two general strategies here would be merging and rebasing.  If you want to *merge* `develop` into `fix` then you can try the following:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout fix
git merge origin/develop
git push origin fix
```

If you want to rebase, the steps are slightly more complicated:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout fix
git rebase origin/develop
git push --force origin fix
```

Note in the final step above we must do a force push (`git push --force`) because rebasing `fix` on `develop` *rewrites* the history of the `fix` branch, such that is has a new *base*.

Which of these two methods you choose depends on several things.  Beginners in Git often gravitate towards merging because it is familiar to them from other VCS tools and is conceptually simple.  On other other hand, rebasing is a bit more complex, but has the benefit of generally preserving the history of a Git branch.

Comment: I think he wants to merge fix to develop?